# Positive, negative, or ambiguous unit test messages?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, message

In most unit test frameworks one can specify a message to be associated with an assertion. I've never been sure how best to use these messages and, as a result, often do so inconsistently.

An example:

```
// a positive message
assertTrue("sean is cool", sean.isCool());

// a negative message
assertTrue("sean is not cool", sean.isCool());

// an ambiguous message
assertTrue("sean's coolness", sean.isCool());
```

I tend to lean toward the second example, providing a 'negative' message, such that, when the test fails, a message is displayed indicating the *cause* of the failure. However, when looking at messages for passed tests, they are inherently misleading. The 'ambiguous' message is most applicable to both passed and failed tests.. but yields less information in either case.

I know this isn't an objective question, but perhaps there is a documented recommended practice defined somewhere.

Comment: I think it is a good question and people with solid unit testing experience could share with their insight in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The message is meant to be used in case of a test failure, so you can be as negative as you only want.

> Optionally the first parameter can be a String message that is output on failure.

[[link]](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I tend towards using should/must:

```
assertTrue("sean should be cool", sean.isCool());
```

This is generally enough for me. If required you can even add more of an explanation

```
assertTrue("sean should be cool, but is not", sean.isCool());
```